# LightDM: user-session doesn't work, nor do multiple sessions at start

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm, 14.10, auto-login, kodi

On my media center (XUbuntu 14.10), I am trying to autostart Kodi in the focussed session and also start and autologin xfce4 in a second unfocussed session (I hope Steam In-Home Streaming doesn't need focus).

Below is my /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf The autologin part works well However, the user-session seems to be completely ignored. I am always send to XFCE. Also a second session is not started.

The respective session files exist:

```
$ ls /usr/share/xsessions/
kodi.desktop  xfce.desktop  xubuntu.desktop
```

(xfce.desktop and xubuntu.desktop seem to be identical)

I can also start kodi-standalone by changing the session in the login screen manually. Any ideas?

```
[LightDM]
seats=Seat:0, Seat:1

[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=kodi
autologin-user-timeout=0
user-session=kodi

[Seat:0]
# Media Center - focussed on boot
vt=7
# Make XBMC start on exit - there is no escape, ever.
greeter-hide-users=true
allow-guest=false
xserver-allow-tcp=false

[Seat:1]
vt=8
# Optional login on Ctrl+Alt+F8
user-session=xubuntu
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and got the same problem.

Except regular lightdm config files I also found these files:

- `$HOME/.dmrc`
- `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/<yourname>`
- `/var/cache/lightdm/dmrc/<yourname>.dmrc`

Changing `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/<yourname>` and replacing the default value `ubuntu` with your session name seems to be the solution.
However I am not sure is there a better way to modify this config rather than changing the file directly.

I also manually modified `.dmrc` and that cache file (needs root permission to go into the folder). However maybe a reboot will update them automatically as they look like just cache.

Answer (score 0):

Same for me, except that it is blackbox for me instead of xfce.

I checked the lightdm log files and I have no clue where it still thinks to start up blackbox instead of kodi as everything looks correctly set.

What I did was at the end a dirty hack. 
I symlinked /usr/share/xsessions/blackbox.desktop to /usr/share/xsessions/kodi.desktop

Kodi starts up finally.

Comment: Doesn't your kodi start up at all or just not as autostart? What Linux are you using? Any idea where to file the bug report? LightDM?